# iPod deactivated and won't connect with Itunes

Tags: touch, itunes, restore, ipod

I have an old (perhaps 10 years old) iPod that has been lying in a drawer for the better half of 5 years, and I would like to restore it. The problem is that the iPod is deactivated, and when I turn it on it says "iPod Deactivated, connect to iTunes to proceed". However, when I downloaded iTunes to connect it, the computer gave me the error message "Unable to connect to iPod because the iPod has a pin-code attached. Enter pincode to proceed". I can't enter the pincode because I only get the "Deactivated" screen, and no other option. I've tried several tutorials on how to restore iPods, and they claim holding in the home button while connecting it should work, aswell as holding in the home button and the lock-screen button at the same time, but none of these solutions seem to work for me. Does anyone have any idea as to why this "paradox" has occured? How can I buypass iTunes? I'm fine with all the content from the iPod being wiped, so any solution would be fine.
Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try and factory reset the iPod when you connect to iTunes, or maybe restore the old backup you have on your computer

Comment: I haven't got a backup, unfortunatly. And I can't connect the iPod to iTunes because I can't enter the pin-code. When the Computer gives me the error message, i only get the "try again" and "cancel" options. My options are limited. Thank you for the reply though :)